# MySQLdump to directory with WinSCP or similar

Tags: mysql, shell, winscp

On my CentOS VPS server I currently backup all my hosted website files via an automated SFTP session using a script. I use WinSCP for this. Unfortunately, this does not include a backup of the MySQL databases which I have about 20 of.

Is it best to run a scheduled dump of the databases into a folder and then ftp this over, or can I use WinSCP to dump them, individually, on-the-fly into a folder during a session? I would prefer the latter option.

If so, how do I achieve this?

I want to end up with a working backup of my databases, on my local Windows PC, that can be reinstated if required.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the WinSCP command `call` to run the `mysqldump`, before you start the download (i.e. before the `get` or `synchronize` command).

For examples see:
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_call

You may need to increase a session timeout (15s default) to allow the `call` to finish in time.

---

Alternatively you can run the `mysqldump` using a more appropriate tool, like `plink` (from PuTTY suite), before you start WinSCP script:
https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter7.html

Comment: Thanks Martin, that works nicely. WinSCP is an excellent tool by the way.

Answer (score 1):

`scp` (and its windows client variant you're using, `WinSCP`) are best for file copying.  You could use `ssh` to run a command to dump each of your databases and then copy them.

But you are probably better off setting up a scheduled dump of each database that operates locally to the CentOS server.

If you happen to be using one of the well-known content management systems for your website (like WordPress, etc) you should investigate the various excellent and free (free as in speech, free as in beer) backup plugins available for those systems.

Comment: Thanks Ollie. I have run manual db backups via SSH but automation is my real aim here. I have also had failures of WP plugins and would like to minimize reliance on these.